# How to choose the row from a numpy's array for which a specific column's value is the largest?

Tags: python, numpy

Given an array of a particular shape (m, n), I'd like to choose the whole row (or find its index) for which a specific's column value is the largest.

Consider the array below. I'd like to find the row where a value of the second column is the largest. The biggest value of the second columns is 0.795, so I should return `[0.21212121,  0.795]`.

```
array([[-3.        ,  0.5       ],
       [-2.93939394,  0.5       ],
       [-2.87878788,  0.5       ],
       [ 0.21212121,  0.795     ],
       [ 0.27272727,  0.785     ],
       [ 0.33333333,  0.785     ],
       [ 0.39393939,  0.77      ],
       [ 2.93939394,  0.5       ],
       [ 3.        ,  0.5       ]])
```

I have achieved the desired result in the following way:

```
best_result = np.max(acc_m[:, 1])
row_with_best_res = acc_m[acc_m[:, 1] == best_result]
```

where `acc_m` is the name of the array.

The presented solution works, but I can't believe that there's no fancier, pythonic way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`np.argmax()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html)

In your case

```
row_with_best_res = acc_m[acc_m[:, 1].argmax()]
```

Comment: This is doing the same thing in a reduced way : `row_with_best_res = acc_m[acc_m.argmax(0)[1]]`

Comment: @Nenri why bother computing the argmax of more than the column you need?  What if there were thousands of columns? Better to only access what you need.  I'd also argue that not being explicit with indexing makes it much more unclear what you are doing.

Comment: That is just a proposal, and it has almost no effect on computation, even with thousands of columns. and some persons can find it clearer. It's always nice to have several ways

Answer (score 0):

You can use the argmax function:

```py
row = acc_m[np.argmax(acc_m[:, 1])]
print(row)
```

```
[0.21212121 0.795     ]
```

Comment: This is doing the same thing in a reduced way : `row = acc_m[np.argmax(acc_m, 0)[1]]`